# Dump part of Java Flight Record

Tags: java, jfr, java-mission-control

Suppose I have configured a continuous flight record for my JVM using the following flags

```
java
-XX:StartFlightRecording=disk=false,dumponexit=true
-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=memorysize=200m
-jar
....
```

As far as I understand, this configuration stores up to 200mb in memory of hotspot events, discarding the oldest when the limit is reached.

To dump the record I'm using `JFR.dump` command via `jcmd`. There's also an alternative way to extract the recording via mission control, but due to a bug in it, I had no success extracting a record that was running outside mission control's JVM. Surprisingly, MBean server management works fine.

Regardless, I saw that it is possible to specify interval range to dump from a continuous recording via "Dump" functionality via mission control, for example from 2021-01-01 13:00:00 to 2021-01-01 14:00:00. Assume current time is 2021-01-02 17:00:00. How do I specify same interval via `JFR.dump`? Looking at [JFR.dump](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-5/jfr-command-reference/diagnostic-command-reference.htm#JFRCR-GUID-6EB11926-4DAF-4B99-AF20-7FCD284EE6C1) reference, there aren't any flags to do that. So how does mission control do it?

Note: I'm using JMC 8 and Oracle JDK 11 0 10u8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, the link you have ranks high in search engines, but it is six years old. You can find the latest documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/jcmd.html) (JDK 16), which is very much the same as JDK 11.

It's not possible to dump part of a memory-based recording. In your example, you have to remove 'disk=false' and -XX:FlightRecorderOptions, and add 'maxsize=200M' to -XX:StartFlightRecording:

```
$ java -XX:StartFlightRecording:maxsize=200M -jar ...
```

Then you can do:

```
$ jcmd <pid> JFR.dump begin=2021-01-01T13:00:00 end=2021-01-01T14:00:00
```

The date time format is [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which is what LocalDataTime.toString() and Instant.toString() produces.

If you omit the end time, JFR.dump will assume it should end when you do the dump, and if you specify a relative time, it will be relative to the dump time.

For example, to dump the last hour:

```
$ jcmd <pid> JFR.dump begin=-1h
```

You can also use the maxage parameter to limit the data, for example:

```
$ jcmd <pid> JFR.dump maxage=1h
```

The maxsize parameter can be used to specify how much data to include, for example:

```
$ jcmd <pid> JFR.dump maxsize=50MB
```

Another alternative is to create two disk-based recordings:

```
$ java -XX:StartFlightRecording:maxsize=200M,name=sized
       -XX:StartFlightRecording:maxage=1h,name=aged 
       -jar ...

$ jcmd <pid> JFR.dump name=aged
```

The overhead of two recordings are the same as one.

(I wouldn't be too concerned about overhead of a disk-based recording. All data in JFR is written lock-free and flushed by a background thread. The difference in overhead between disk and memory is usually not measurable)

Comment: as a side note, is there a mailing list to report issues with mission control?

Comment: https://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/jmc-dev